# Buffering in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Currently I am working on the application for which I have to use audio buffering. Please tell me how I can achieve this task as I am trying myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this [Buffer and play streamed media](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Buffer_and_play_streamed_media_740033_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's a great example in the Blackberry SDK, which shows buffered playback of a MP3 file.
Take a look in the 'samples' folder of JDE/Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: you should accept the answer that suits you. just click a check sign near the answer.